# request.getHeader("Referer") is not working

Tags: jsp, url

I was using the following code to get the previous url in my jsp.

```
 String Str = new String(request.getHeader("Referer")); 
 out.println("Str:"+Str);
```

`Str` returns the correct `url` every time except while clicking on `browser back button`. Why is this happening? Or how can I get the previous url this time?

Comment: you can't, at least not in a reliable manner - "Back button" is one of the most problematic things from a server-perspective... see [here](http://jordanhollinger.com/2012/06/08/disable-the-back-button-using-html5) and [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: If you need the previous URL, you put it into a session at the moment it is called – and then retrieve it from there on the next page. (This will be problematic if the user opens multiple tabs). What do you need that info for anyway?

Comment: @CBroe: When I set session in one page say `page="a"` in `a.jsp` and `page="c"` in `c.jsp`. I am printing session value in `b.jsp`. I click on back button from `c to b`. In `b.jsp` session is not changing, ie still `page="a"`.

Comment: Sure that’s not a caching issue? (And the question what you actually need this for is still unanswered.)

Comment: For your query: I need to perform some task in say, `a.jsp` if the user click back button from a page `b.jsp`.(click on back button from b will redirect to a).
On my previous comment: After clicking back button, if I refresh the page, then session is changing(fine).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Encoding Sensitive Information in URI's](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3)

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
>   HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
>   protocol.
>
> Authors of services which use the HTTP protocol SHOULD NOT use GET
>   based forms for the submission of sensitive data, because this will
>   cause this data to be encoded in the Request-URI.

Probably in POST redirected requests you may get it.